# Can you set queues equal to each other?

Tags: c++, queue

For example, if I have one queue of `int` named Q with the values (from front to back) 0, 1, 2, and 3, can I just create another queue of `int` and set them equal to each other to copy data from one another?

Here is an example:

> Write a C++ Function `queue<int> copy_queue(queue<int> &Q)` that returns a new queue containing all of the items in Q in the same order that they were found in Q. The original queue Q must end up unchanged.

Would it be possible to just do something like:

```
queue<int> copy_queue(queue<int> &Q){    
  queue<int>Q2 = Q; 
  return Q2;
}
```

Comment: Try it out. Also add `const` to the parameter, so we can trust the statement such as: *"The original queue Q must end up unchanged."*

Comment: Did you try it?  Did it work?  Are you using a `std::queue` or some home grown one?

Comment: [Sure](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/operator%3D).

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Actually the third overload [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/queue) :) But there won't be one without the other, I guess.

Comment: @LogicStuff Oops, yes of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would it be possible to just do something like: ...

Almost. Remember the requirement

> > The original queue Q must end up unchanged.

Add a `const` to the reference parameter to guarantee that:

```
std::queue<int> copy_queue(const std::queue<int> &Q) {    
                        // ^^^^^
    std::queue<int>Q2 = Q; 
    return Q2;
}
```

---

Note that this `copy_queue()` function looks pretty useless, since simply using

```
std::queue<int>Q2 = Q;
```

already does what you want.

See [`std::queue<T>::queue(const std::queue<T>& other)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/queue/queue) please.

Comment: no need for const here. It's good style, I know, but there's no need for it